# In Yii framework what's the best method to log in database URL's accessed by users?

Tags: php, yii

I need to log in database every url's accessed by my registered users. At the moment I log when they do a login in my system, but I need to log every page they access.

Where is the best place or the best method to do this using Yii Framework?

I noticed that I can use the beforeRender() or the beforeAction() methods to do this. Which is the best? There is another way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to evaluate one of the several extension for auditing and logging, 
like   http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-audit-module/ or

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/audittrail/ ..

If these are not useful you i think the `beforeAction` method/event is more interesting , beacuse you could intercept behavior not related to render

Comment: I've used the beforeAction and it works well for what I need. Thanks!